# Insert a new object into a sub-document array field in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

```json
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("579de5ad16944ccc24d5f4f1"),
    "dots" : 
    [
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "location" : 
            [
                 {
                    "lx" : 10,
                    "ly" : 10
                 }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "location" : [{}]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Above is json format of model (from mongobooter) let's say "lines", and i have _id and dots.id and i want to add new object into location. then how can i do that (using mongoose)?

Comment: which location? the dots array?

Comment: "location" with in dots array object.....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can choose between:

Mongoose Object-way:

```
document.dots[0].location.push({ /* your subdoc*/ });
document.save(callback);
```

Mongo/Mongoose Query (using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) and [`$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)):

```
YourModel.update(
  {_id: /* doc id */, 'dots.id': /* subdoc id */ },
  {$push: {'dots.$.location': { /* your subdoc */ }},
  callback
);
```

Comment: how if the data that I want to push more than one?

Comment: How would you deal with this if you could not use the index of dots?