# Popiulate sub docs in mongoose

Tags: mongoose, save, documents

I'm having trouble with a save on subdocument.

Im calling save method on parent model but it only saves once. When theres one subdocument it does not save another one.

```
const reply = await Comment
    .save({
      _id: commentID,
      answers: [{
        author: author,
        content: content
      }]
    })
```

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751676/insert-a-new-object-into-a-sub-document-array-field-in-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your schema for answers is the `Schema.Types.Mixed`. If you modify these, you need to use `markModified` to tell Mongoose that you changed it (this only applies to Mixed, not String or anything else like that).

```
//change your doc...
Comment.markModified('answers');
Comment.save({...})
```